Unable to find the downloaded open-telemetry service in Amazon Linux 1
I am trying to install and enable opentelemetry to collect system-level metrics from EC2 instances. I am doing so as these metrics have to be scraped from system-level and Cloudwatch doesn't export it.
Link where I am downloading OTLP from - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases/releases/download/v0.82.0/otelcol-contrib_0.82.0_linux_amd64.rpm
I was able to successfully collect metrics from centos linux machines but not on Amazon Linux 1 - Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03 machines. One option is to update the OS but I need to wait for a maintenance window and this is weeks away.
systemctl cannot be installed on these machines. I checked the services using service --status-all and I do see
====
OTLP
====

  Status: Not enabled
  Collector status: Not running

I tried service OTLP start and it doesn't work. I used chkconfig --list to find the service and still couldn't find the OTLP service.
How do I enable and start this service to collect metrics?
TIA.
